# How to open a window with a click of a button from another window using PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, window, buttonclick

I'm trying to make an application but I keep getting punched by the "simple" things like this one, how do I open a new window though a button click? I tried using `new_lib_btn.clicked.connect(newlib)`, `newlib` is the file that contains my second window and `new_lib_btn` is the button that should open the window, it's in my main window as you can see down here:

`mainwindow.py`

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import newlib
import sys
# Main Window

class Window (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)
        self.mainLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Virtual Library")
        self.setStyleSheet("Window {border-image: url(lib.jpg);}")

        # ExitOption
        menu_action1 = QtGui.QAction("Exit", self)
        menu_action1.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        menu_action1.setStatusTip('Exit The App')
        menu_action1.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        self.statusBar()

        # MenuBar
        main_menu = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = main_menu.addMenu('Options')
        file_menu.addAction(menu_action1)



        self.home()

    def home(self):
        # NewLibrary btn
        new_lib_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("New Library", self)
        new_lib_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 180, 141, 41))
        new_lib_btn.setStyleSheet("color: black;")

        # AccessLibrary btn
        access_lib_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Access Library", self)
        access_lib_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 250, 141, 41))
        access_lib_btn.setStyleSheet("color: black;")

        # FindNewBooks btn
        find_nbooks = QtGui.QPushButton("Find New Books*", self)
        find_nbooks.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 320, 141, 41))
        find_nbooks.setStyleSheet("color: black;")

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(new_lib_btn)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(access_lib_btn)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(find_nbooks_btn)
        self.show()

    def close_application(self):
        choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit',
                                        "Close the application?",
                                        QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass


def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

And here's my second window, the one I want to open with the `new_lib_btn`

`newlib.py`

```
class NewLibrary (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
         super(NewLibrary, self).__init__()

         self.resize(800,600)
         self.setWindowTitle("New Library")
         self.setStyleSheet("NewLibrary {border-image: url(wood.jpg);}")

         # File Options
         file_action1 = QtGui.QAction("New Library", self)
         file_action1.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
         file_action1.setStatusTip("Creates a new library")

         file_action2 = QtGui.QAction("Exit this!", self)
         file_action2.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
         file_action2.setStatusTip("Closes The App")
         file_action2.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

         #File Menu
         main_menu = self.menuBar()
         file_menu = main_menu.addMenu("File")
         file_menu.addAction(file_action1)
         file_menu.addAction(file_action2)
         self.newLib()

         self.newLib()

     def newLib(self):
         centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
         self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)
         self.mainLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

         #some useful buttons in the future

         self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
         self.show()

     def close_application(self):
         choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit',
                                        "Close the application?",
                                        QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
         if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
             sys.exit()
         else:
             pass
def runNewLib():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = NewLibrary()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
runNewLib()
```

I searched a lot about this but I couldn't understand the few ones that were somewhat close to my situation, so I'm asking for help, It seems so simple but I'm not getting it :/, what should I do to open the second window by clicking `new_lib_btn`? pls help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there are several issues with the code that you've posted. First, there are two calls to `self.newLib()` in the `NewLibrary` constructor. Second, you probably want to put that call to `runNewLib()` at the bottom of `newlib.py` behind an `if __name__...` block, like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    runNewLib()
```

Otherwise, every time you try to import `newlib.py`, it will attempt to run NewLibrary as a separate application.

Getting to the question you asked, I don't think you actually want to call `self.show()` in either `Window.home()` or `NewLibrary.newLib()`. A more typical pattern would be to create an instance of either `Window` or `NewLibrary` and then call `show()` on that instance. So, in your `Window` class, you'd add a function to create an instance of `NewLibrary` and then call show on it, like this

```
def create_new_library_window(self):
    self.new_lib = newlib.NewLibrary()
    self.new_lib.show()
```

Note that, as ekhumoro points out, you have to keep a reference to new_lib around, otherwise it will get garbage collected when the function exits. Then in `NewLibrary.home()` after you've created the `new_lib_btn` connect it to this new function:

```
new_lib_btn.clicked.connect(self.create_new_library_window)
```

**Working example**

This example creates a main window with one big button that, when clicked will open a second window. It uses two classes that inherit from QMainWindow, as in your question. First, in `main.py`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from new_window import NewWindow


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self._new_window = None
        self._button = QtGui.QPushButton('New Window', self)
        self._button.clicked.connect(self.create_new_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._button)

    def create_new_window(self):
        self._new_window = NewWindow()
        self._new_window.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    gui = Window()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The `__init__` function creates a button and connects it to the `create_new_window` function. When the button is clicked, `create_new_window` will be called. Inside of `create_new_window`, we create an instance of `NewWindow` and assign it to a class member to maintain a reference to the window and prevent it from being garbage collected. We then call `show` on this new window to display it.

At the bottom, we use the usual `if __name__ == '__main__':` pattern to control whether this file runs the application or not. If this file is executed from the command line (like `python main.py`) `__name__ == '__main__'` evaluates to true and the GUI application will be started. This has the advantage of allowing the file to serve a dual purpose: it can be imported as a standard python package, or executed as an application, all using the same file.

Then in `new_window.py`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class NewWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewWindow, self).__init__()
        self._new_window = None
        self._label = QtGui.QLabel('Hello, is it me you\'re looking for?')
        self.setCentralWidget(self._label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    gui = NewWindow()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This file defines a second QMainWindow that uses a label as its central widget. It also uses the `__name__ == '__main__'` pattern; this file can also be executed as a standalone application or imported as in `main.py` above.

Comment: I've fixed the double call to self.newLib(), and substituted the simple run() for the If __name__... but I didn't really get the other part, I mean should I create a function like the one you post it for the Window too? 'cause I tried it but I didn't know how or where to call it in the code so I didn't know if I should've done that for the Window, I tried but I only got errors, so I let the self.show() there to try to use the create_new_library_window() in the button but again I got an error that said that window didn't had the create_... attribute, sorry, I'm a noob, could u explain again?

Comment: The `create_new_library_window` is incomplete. It needs a `self` argument, and should be a method of the `Window` class. It also needs to keep a reference to `new_lib`, otherwise the new window will just be garbage-collected when the method returns (i.e. `self.new_lib = newlib.NewLibrary(); self.new_lib.show()`).

Comment: @ekhumoro makes good points. I've edited my answer to try to address these shortcomings and added a working example to try to explain exactly where all the functions live.